# React PWA Design Breaks on iOS Mobile Devices

Tags: ios, reactjs, tailwind-css, progressive-web-apps, vite

I have developed a Progressive Web App (PWA) using Vite-React, Tailwind, Next-UI and it functions flawlessly on Android devices across various browsers. The design and layout are responsive and display perfectly on Android smartphones.

However, I've encountered an issue when accessing the same PWA on iOS mobile devices. On iOS, the design seems to break in multiple places, resulting in a less-than-ideal user experience.

I've thoroughly tested the PWA on different browsers on iOS (e.g., Safari, Chrome), but the issue persists. I've also ensured that the CSS and layout settings are consistent across both Android and iOS.

I'm puzzled as to why this is happening and how to resolve it. I'd appreciate any insights or solutions that the community might have. Has anyone else experienced a similar problem with React PWAs on iOS? Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

The left image is of android-chrome, and the right one is of ios-chrome. You can see how the design is breaking. And most importantly the whole website is responsive, the only issue is coming on ios.
[image]

This is the code for the particular bottom navigation

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// ** import shared components
import Typography from '@shared/Typography';
import Button from '@shared/Button';

// ** import assets
import CartSvg from '@icons/CartSvg';
import DishSvg from '@icons/DishSvg';
import HomeSvg from '@icons/HomeSvg';

// ** import for translation
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

// ** import utils
import cn from '@utils/cn';

const BottomMenu = () => {
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
const { t } = useTranslation();

const BottomMenuData = [
{ svg: <HomeSvg active />, inActiveSvg: <HomeSvg />, title: t('home'), to:"/menu" },
{ svg: <DishSvg active />, inActiveSvg: <DishSvg />, title: t('magic'), to:"/magic-items" },
{ svg: <CartSvg active />, inActiveSvg: <CartSvg />, title: t('cart'), to:"/order" },
];

return (
<div className=" fixed bottom-0 left-0 right-0 px-6  pb-4 bg-primary-white shadow-custom2">
  <div className=" flex justify-between">

  {BottomMenuData.map((nav, index) => (
    <Button
      key={index}
      variant="plain"
      link={nav.to}
      className={cn(
        'pt-3 flex flex-col items-center',
        index == selectedIndex &&
        'border-t-4 !rounded-none border-primary-orange',
        index == selectedIndex
        ? 'text-primary-orange'
          : 'text-primary-gray',
          )}
      onClick={() => {
        setSelectedIndex(index);
      }}
      >
      {index == selectedIndex ? nav.svg : nav.inActiveSvg}

      <Typography variant="P_Medium_H6" className={'pt-3'}>
        {nav.title}
      </Typography>
    </Button>
  ))}
  </div>
</div>
);
};

export default BottomMenu;
```